# PHP: Why not get the data of the image that I will insert into the database?

Tags: php, file-upload

I've the next problem: The code to validate the name, address and email works, but to validate the image does not work and do not know why that happens. As always prints "Select an image"

I did a test and set the line to print the temporary name of the image with **"print $photo"** but nothing prints!

**form.php**

```
<form id="formregister" name="formregister" action="register.php" method="post">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
    <input id="address" name="address"  type="text"/>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />
    <input id="photouser" name="imguser" type="file"/>
    <input id="bregister" name="bregister" type="submit" value="Registrer"/>
</form>
```

**register.php**

```
..............
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$photo = $_FILES['imguser']['tmp_name'];
$errors = array();

    if(!isset($photo)) {
        $errors[] = "Select an image";
    } else {
        $fototemp = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imguser']['tmp_name']));
        $fotoname = addslashes($_FILES['imguser']['name']);
        $fotosize = getimagesize($_FILES['imguser']['tmp_name']);
        if ($fotosize == false) {
            $errors[] = "Invalid format";
        }
    } 
//Code to validate the other fields (name, address, email)
....................
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with those `addslashes()` calls?  If you're inserting this to a database, that probably isn't the correct escaping method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the proper `enctype` for file uploads on your form. It should be `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

```
<form id="formregister" name="formregister" action="register.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Rather than accessing the secondary `tmp_name` key directly, test if it is set first to avoid undefined index notices:

```
if (isset($_FILES['imguser']) {
  $photo = $_FILES['imguser']['tmp_name'];
}
```